# Where oil is used for

Tags: climate-change, climate, oil-reserves

I am trying to study climate change and lately, I am realizing that oil companies were/are drilling for oils at Alaska, Arctic, Antarctica.
Where oil (which oil company drills) is used maximum for?
I am looking for some exhaustive list.
I am reading some sources but they are mostly vague and too shallow like for gas in vehicles , electricity etc.
Any answer which provides exhaustive list or exhaustive material which I can study (even books are cool with me) are appreciated.

Comment: There is no drilling for oil in Antarctica.  The only drilling which takes place there is for scientific purposes, as when the Russians recently drilled down to Lake Vostok.

Comment: you wonder what we use oil for is this correct?

Comment: In the US, there are many oil places that are found on the federal lands and prevent from the Oil companies to drill more so we depend the oil from the Middle East.

Comment: Oil is fungible so where it is produced is no indication of where / what product it may. used. Simply it makes modern society possible. Fuel to plow fields , produce fertilizer , process production into food. Electric cars must have batteries and metal bodies mined  and processed with oil fueled equipment ; have plastic and fabric interiors made nearly all oil derived stuff. And  essentially all the rest of the stuff you use everyday.

Comment: @trondhansen Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for their useful additions , Do you guys can help me with more resources or books which I can study because I am from Computer Science background and I have a very myopic view of how oil (apart from what is used in vehicles) is used in our day to day life?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

[OilPrice](https://oilprice.com/Energy/Crude-Oil/Peak-Oil-Myth-Or-Coming-Reality.html)

Petrochemicals are used to make numerous products.
[image]
[Source](https://energi.media/news/petrochemical-products-in-everyday-life/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, do you know about any more resources or books which I can study because I am from Computer Science background and I have very myopic view of how oil (apart from what is used in vehicles) is used in our day to day life.

Comment: @Mark I'm not sure what you're looking for. Googling for **world petroleum consumption** I find for example: https://www.bp.com/content/dam/bp/business-sites/en/global/corporate/pdfs/energy-economics/statistical-review/bp-stats-review-2018-full-report.pdf , https://www.eia.gov/energyexplained/oil-and-petroleum-products/use-of-oil.php , https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/statistics-explained/index.php?title=Oil_and_petroleum_products_-_a_statistical_overview&oldid=448293#Use_of_petroleum_products .